# Query string parameters from Javascript do not make it to processing PHP  script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to populate a [jQWidgets listbox](http://www.jqwidgets.com/listbox-with-checkboxes/) control on my webpage(when page finished loading and rendering) with values from an actual MySQL database table.

**PARTIAL SOLUTION:** [Here](http://www.jqwidgets.com/populate-a-listbox-with-data-from-mysql-database-using-php/)

**NEW PROBLEM:**
I've updated the source code and if I hardcode the SQL string - the listbox gets populated. But I want to make a small JS function - popList(field, table) - which can be called when you want to generate a jQWidgets listbox with values from a MySQL database on a page.

**Problem** is - for some reason the `$field` and `$table` are empty when the PHP script is being executed, and I receive `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM' at line 1` error. What gives?

**The page**:

```
            <div id="ListBox">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                popList("name", "categories");
            </script>
            </div>
```

**popList(***field*, *value***)**:

```
    function popList(field, table) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'getListOfValues.php',
        data: 'field='+escape(field)+'&table='+escape(table),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            var source = $.parseJSON(response);
            $("#ListBox").jqxListBox({ source: source, checkboxes: true, width: '400px', height: '150px', theme: 'summer'});
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('sources unavailable');
        }
    });
}
```

**getListOfValues.php**:

```
    <?php
    require "dbinfo.php";

    // Opens a connection to a MySQL server
    $connection=mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
    if (!$connection) {
        die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
    }

    // Set the active MySQL database
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
    if (!$db_selected) {
        die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $field = $_GET["field"];
    $table = $_GET["table"];

    $field = mysql_real_escape_string($field);
    $table = mysql_real_escape_string($table);

    $qryString = "SELECT " . $field . " FROM " . $table;

    $qryResult = mysql_query($qryString) or die(mysql_error());

    $source = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qryResult)){
        array_push($source, $row[$field]);
    }

    mysql_close($connection);

    echo json_encode($source);
?>
```

Comment: I'm wondering if the word name or categories in your query would need to be escaped properly with `. Also, can you add a print_r($_GET); to the top of your PHP script and paste what the output is?

Comment: @Michael Taggart

I tried both. And print_r is empty.

Comment: hrmmmmm. If print_r($_GET); doesn't return anything then that means the javascript is not posting the variables at all. Can you add this above the $.ajax line in popList():
alert('field='+escape(field)+'&table='+escape(table));

Make sure that you see the data in the alert window.

Comment: also do you have a URL where I can take a look at what you're trying to do?

Comment: Try removing the var source = $.parseJSON(response); line and then change the next line to source: response  This is because jQuery will automatically parse the JSON for you if you have dataType: 'json'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, you have a few things here. First off you need a callback function when you do the ajaxRequest. (I'll explain why in a bit.) So add the following line BEFORE your ajaxReqest.send(null);

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = processAjaxResponse;
```

Then you need to add the processAjaxResponse function which will be called.

```
function processAjaxResponse() {
    if (ajaxRequest.readySTate == 4) {
        var response = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        //do something with the response
        //if you want to decode the JSON returned from PHP use this line
        var arr = eval(response);
    }
}
```

Ok, now the problem on your PHP side is you are using the return method. Instead you want PHP to print or echo output. Think about it this way. Each ajax call you do is like an invisible browser. Your PHP script needs to print something to the screen for the invisible browser to grab and work with.

In this specific case you are trying to pass an array from PHP back to JS so json_encode is your friend.  Change your return line to the following:

```
print json_encode($listOfReturnedValues);
```

Let me know if you have any questions or need any help beyond this point. As an aside, I would really recommend using something like jQuery to do the ajax call and parse the response. Not only will it make sure the ajax call is compliant in every browser, it can automatically parse the JSON response into an array/object/whatever for you. Here's what your popList function would look like in jQuery (NOTE: you wouldn't need the processAjaxResponse function above)

```
function popList(field,table) {
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'getListofValues.php',
            data: 'field='+escape(field)+'&table='+escape(table),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                //the response variable here would have your array automatically decoded
            }
        });
}
```

It's just a lot cleaner and easier to maintain. I had to go back to some old code to remember how I did it before ;)

Good luck!

Comment: I tried to implement your version of `popList()` but for some reason the `field` and `table` values do not get to the PHP script and I end up with an empty listbox. I've updated all three source codes in my question and added a detailed description of my current problem, so if you happen to know what is causing this feel free to check the source.

Comment: Hmmm, if you have "dataType: 'json'" then I believe the response variable is already json decoded for you. Meaning it gets turned into an array/object whatever behind the scenes.

It looks like you are just passing the response straight through to the jqxListBox function in string form. Try changing dataType to html so that jQuery doesn't do any automatic parsing.

Comment: @Bob it looks like your query would look like this: